# React Native - panResponder animation not working on iOS

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, drag-and-drop, draggable

I use a panResponder to create draggable view in my app. It's working fine on android but on iOS, the drag animation stops after moving la little bit.

[Vidéo here](https://www.facebook.com/alexandre.boulme/videos/10217808263985570/)
Here is my code :

```
export default class Draggable extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  const { pressDragRelease, pressDragStart, reverse, initPosition } = props;

this.state = {
  pan: new Animated.ValueXY({
    x: initPosition.dragX,
    y: initPosition.dragY
  }),
  _value: { x: initPosition.dragX, y: initPosition.dragY }
};

this.panResponder = PanResponder.create({
  onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
  onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => true,
  onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
  onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => true,
  onPanResponderGrant: (gesture) => {
    console.log("inside panResponder grant");
    if (reverse === false) {
      this.state.pan.setOffset({x: this.state._value.x,y: this.state._value.y});
      this.state.pan.setValue({ x: 0, y: 0 });
    } else {
      this.state.pan.setValue({ x: gesture.dx, y: gesture.dy });
    }
  },
  onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([
      null,
      {
        dx: this.state.pan.x,
        dy: this.state.pan.y
      }
    ]),
    //Called on android at the end
    onPanResponderRelease: () => {
      if (pressDragRelease) {
        pressDragRelease({ x: this.state._value.x, y: this.state._value.y });
      }

    if (reverse === false) this.state.pan.flattenOffset();
    else this.reversePosition();

  },
  //Called on ios at the end
  onPanResponderTerminate: () => {

    if (pressDragRelease) {
      pressDragRelease({ x: this.state._value.x, y: this.state._value.y 
   });
    }

    if(reverse === false) {
      this.state.pan.flattenOffset();
    } else {
      this.reversePosition();
    }

  }
});
}

componentWillMount() {
 if (this.props.reverse === false)
   this.state.pan.addListener(c => this.setState({ _value: c }));
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.state.pan.removeAllListeners();
}

reversePosition = () => {
  const { initPosition } = this.props;
  Animated.spring(this.state.pan, {
    toValue: { x: initPosition.dragX, y: initPosition.dragY }
  }).start();
};

render() {
  return (
    <Animated.View
      {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}
      style={[this.state.pan.getLayout()]}
    >
      {this.props.children}
    </Animated.View>
   );
  }
}
```

I'm using : 
"react-native": "0.57.7"

I tried lots of things related to panResponder, as it works fine on android I guest it's an issue of handler or of the Animated.event in onPanResponderMove handler ?

Any help appreciated, I'm struggling on it for several days ! :)

Comment: did you already use Animated timing with ease.Easing.linear?

Comment: I just try some animation with "Animated.timing" and it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Also ran into this issue.
Deleted my node modules and pods with a reinstall which was able to resolve it.

I know in the past react-navigation conflicted.
https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/5497

Actually ran into this while using a slider library which was built using panResponder.

Comment: I'm running into the exact same issue and reinstalling `node_modules` and `pods` didn't fix :(

Comment: I ended up finding that it was an issue with a library. Specifically ux-cam in my case was detecting user's swipes and causing an interaction issue.  
I think you need to start removing libraries until you find the conflicting source.

Comment: It ended up being the same issue for me too! I was pretty pissed and made a PR to the ux cam repo, but they don't really seem to care :(